# Parsing Non-Standard XML in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I need help parsing this XML in TSQL:

```
<Settings>
    <Setting ERName="CAPTURE_MODE_ID" Value="9" />
    <Setting ERName="VEHICLE_TYPE" Value="7" />
</Settings>
```

I would like to return the values as such:

```
Capture_Mode_Id        Vehicle_Type
9                      7
```

Comment: What is non-standard about the XML in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13976)

```sql
declare @XML xml

set @XML = '
<Settings>
 <Setting ERName="CAPTURE_MODE_ID" Value="9" />
 <Setting ERName="VEHICLE_TYPE" Value="7" />
</Settings>'

select @XML.value('(/Settings/Setting[@ERName = "CAPTURE_MODE_ID"]/@Value)[1]', 'int') as CAPTURE_MODE_ID,
       @XML.value('(/Settings/Setting[@ERName = "VEHICLE_TYPE"]/@Value)[1]', 'int') as VEHICLE_TYPE
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13976/0)**:

```
| CAPTURE_MODE_ID | VEHICLE_TYPE |
|-----------------|--------------|
|               9 |            7 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform two logical steps as best I can tell:

1. Parse the XML - i.e. get a result set from it.
2. Pivot the result set.

To get a result set from the XML, use the [`OPENXML` function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx) - something like the following...

```
DECLARE @idoc int, @doc varchar(1000);

-- the XML document
SET @doc ='
<ROOT>
<Settings>
    <Setting ERName="CAPTURE_MODE_ID" Value="9" />
    <Setting ERName="VEHICLE_TYPE" Value="7" />
</Settings>
</ROOT>';

-- Create an internal representation of the XML document.
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc;

-- Execute a SELECT statement that uses the OPENXML rowset provider.
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/Settings/Setting', 1)
    WITH (ERName varchar(20), Value varchar(20));
```

..., which yields the following results:

```
ERName                 Value
---------------        -----
CAPTURE_MODE_ID        9
VEHICLE_TYPE           7
```

To pivot the result set without aggregation, consider the ideas presented to this end in a [CALSQL blog post](http://www.calsql.com/2009/10/pivot-with-out-aggregate.html).